# Как сделать скидки и акции на iap-ы в Google play и Appstore?

Tags: unity3d, google-play, appstore

Стоит задача в игре делать скидки на некоторые товары в определенный момент времени. Например, сделать в пятницу скидку на оффер в 50% от его базовой цены. 
Подскажите, если ли какая нормальная альтернатива, кроме как дублировать каждый товар в сторе с разными скидками? Снижать цену на товар в самом сторе не вариант, т.к хочется делать скидки только для определенных пользователей, а не для всех разом.

Т.е есть товар **gold_pack** c базовой ценой $10 и для того, чтобы сделать скидку на него мы создадим несколько дубликатов:

```
gold_pack_90 с ценой $9
gold_pack_75 с ценой $7.5
gold_pack_50 с ценой $5
gold_pack_25 с ценой $2.5
```

И в зависимости от выбранной скидки на товар будем продавать игроку не базовый iap из магазина, а его копию с нужным размером скидки.

На первый взгляд рабочий вариант, но очень уж муторный в плане занесения всех товаров в консолях магазинов и нет возможности устанавливать произвольные скидки.

Заранее спасибо!